# Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Tags: sql-server

I need this query without using `Group by`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty)
FROM
    MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails a
WHERE
    (ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0)) 
    AND (a.VoucherId=374956)
```

Comment: Well `(ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0))` is not a boolean result. Maybe you're looking for something like `(ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0)) > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every statement you put in the `WHERE` clause needs to result in a `true` or `false`. You have an arithmetic expression that yields a number, but not a `true/false`, what is known as a boolean. This numeric result is not automatically converted to a boolean (as in some other programming languages).

```
WHERE (ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0))
```

You need to change this to, for instance:

```
WHERE (ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0)) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

add condition like `>` , `<` or `=` where you are calculating `UOMQTY`-`Qty`

```
where (ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.UOMQTY, 0) - ISNULL(a.MstSalesCounterVoucherDetails.Qty, 0))>0 AND (a.VoucherId=374956)
```